# The Exact DE of $\dfrac{(xdy - ydx)}{(x^2 + y^2)}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I know the exact DE of  $\dfrac{(xdy - ydx)}{(x^2 + y^2)}$ is $\arctan(y/x)$ but I tried doing it manually, where I integrated $xdy/(x^2 + y^2)$ and got $\arctan(y/x) +$ a function in $x$ which acts as a constant here, and $-ydx/(x^2 + y^2)$ and got $\arctan(x/y) +$ a function in y which acts as a constant. But that is different from the standard result, the combined function I got is $\arctan(y/x) - \arctan(x/y)$, whereas the correct DE is $\arctan(y/x)$ only. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Since I consider this to be the most important exact differential in all of math, I can’t help but comment. $\arctan (y/x)$ is the solution only if you restrict to $x>0$. But the real answer is given by the angle $\theta$ from polar coordinates. If, for example, you restrict to the plane minus the negative $y$ axis, you can restrict to $-\pi < \theta<\pi$ but not to the entire plane. This example is fundamental to areas of math such as differential topology and complex analysis.

Answer (score 3):

First, there's a crucial sign error: Integrating with respect to $x$ gives $$\color{red}{-}\arctan \frac{x}{y} + g(y)$$ for some function $f$. At this we need only reconcile this expression with $\arctan \frac{y}{x} + h(x)$.

**Hint** For $m > 0$, $$\arctan m + \arctan \frac{1}{m} = \frac{\pi}{2} .$$ (To see why, draw a right triangle with legs of length $1, m$ and write down expressions for the acute angles in terms of $\arctan$.)